# Query to get Data from two tables in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have 
Two Tables Parent and Child, like employee and department table.
I want to display department name sorted by the number of times they occur in Employee table,The one with the most occurrences should be listed first.
 please tell me the solution urgent and the SQL statement should Supported by SqlCE

Thanks in advance....

Comment: you should add your schemas.

Comment: it's like basic Emp and Dept tables,still If you want me to post all the table structure, I will post it.

Comment: You should always post your structure. Otherwise people are just guessing at the answer.

Comment: Tikkes got my problem exactly below, but I'm unable to Display dept.Name in the below statement (Sql Statement Written by Tikkes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT dept.Name, COUNT(emp.id) as timesOccurring 
FROM departments dept
INNER JOIN employees emp
ON emp.dept_id = dept.id
GROUP BY dept.Name
ORDER BY timesOccurring
```

That should do it.

Comment: Getting an error:In aggregate and grouping expressions,the select clause can contain only aggregate and grouping expressions

Comment: are you selecting more columns? if you are, make sure that **every** column that is not in an aggregate function (ie. `COUNT()`, `AVG()`,...) is in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: No Used as it is, "SELECT        map.Value, COUNT(tap.MapDetailCellID) AS timesOccurring
FROM            MapDetailCell AS map INNER JOIN
                         TrainingPlanSaved AS tap ON tap.MapDetailCellID = map.id
GROUP BY map.id
ORDER BY timesOccurring DESC  "

Comment: `GROUP BY map.id` -> this goes wrong, you do **not** select map.id, instead change it by `GROUP BY map.value`

Comment: map.value refers html content so that you can't use group by for that column

Comment: Are you saving that in your database? it's plain simple, if you use an aggregate fuction, all other columns **MUST** be in the `GROUP BY` clause or you will get an error. That's just how SQL works.

Comment: "Group by cannot be used with ntext and image data" This the error message I'm getting, Any Other solution for this?

Comment: SELECT COUNT([Category ID])
      ,CAST([Description] AS nvarchar(4000))
  FROM [Categories]
  GROUP BY CAST([Description] AS nvarchar(4000))
GO

Comment: Select  maptbl.value ,maptbl.id, mapdata.timesOccurring From (SELECT        map.id as id, COUNT(tap.MapDetailCellID) AS timesOccurring
FROM            MapDetailCell AS map INNER JOIN
                         TrainingPlanSaved AS tap ON tap.MapDetailCellID = map.id
GROUP BY map.id
) as mapdata Inner Join MapDetailCell as maptbl
On mapdata.id=maptbl.id
Order by mapdata.timesOccurring desc


This is the Solution 
I got it with Tikkes idea
Thanks for your replies
thanks all